# InstagramBot: Ao tentar curtir foto do instagram, classe não é encontrada

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram-api

Comecei a desenvolver uma API para o instagram. Tudo está funcionando normalmente, porém a linha de
código que curtir a publicação não está conseguindo achar a classe.

**A classe:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código para curtir:**

```
        def curtir_fotos(self, hashtag):
        driver = self.driver
        self.hashtag = hashtag
        driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' +hashtag+ '/')
        time.sleep(5)
        for i in range(1, 3):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(3)
        hrefs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        pic_hrefs = [elen.get_attribute('href') for elen in hrefs]
        [href for href in pic_hrefs if hashtag in href]
        print(hashtag + ' fotos: ' +str(len(pic_hrefs)))

        for pic_hrefs in pic_hrefs:
            driver.get(pic_hrefs)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_class_name('//button[@class="_8-yf5 "]').click()
                time.sleep(10)
            except Exception:
                time.sleep(5)
```

Ele sempre cai no except e não sei o porque. Então como resolvo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você poderia tentar com o `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`

***Ficaria assim:***
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#react-root > section > main > div > div.ltEKP > article > div.eo2As > section.ltpMr.Slqrh > span.fr66n > button > div > span > svg").click()`

***Testei e funcionou.***

Para capturar o css
Botão direito no elemento lá no Chrome depois em Inspecionar
Usa **Ctrl+Shirt+C** e seleciona o elemento depois botão direito do mouse no código que foi marcado junto do elemento próximo passo vá em **Copy** e por último **Copy Selector**, agora e só jogar lá no código.

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Pra falar a verdade testei esse e não deu certo de primeira, mas descobrir o problema e estou me sentindo um verdadeiro palhaço. A verdade é que quando executo o código `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` pela segunda vez dentro do for  com os pic_hrefs, ele desce e com isso acaba não encontrando a classe ou mesmo elemento pedido... Estou verdadeiramente feliz e bravo com isso, mas agradeço de verdade por me ajudar, afinal foi a partir disso que descobrir o erro. Obrigado novamente e Boa noite!

Comment: O bom da programação é isso os erros sem eles não descobrimos a solução dentro das entrelinhas. 

Comment: Ainda sou muito novo nisso, mas muito mesmo. e uma coisa boa é a comunidade que ajuda um ao outro.